# Bash snippet doesn't work in makefile

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, gnu-make

I have one version file `verfile` which contains below version string
`V1.1.2`

And in Makefile I intend to read this version string,
So I wrote Makefile as follows,

```
filepath        :=      $(PWD)
versionfile     :=      $(filepath)/verfile

all:
        cat $(versionfile)
        version=$(shell cat $(versionfile))
        echo "version=$(version)"
```

Now when I run the make file I get following ouput

```
cat /home/ubuntu/ankur/verfile
v1.1.2
version=v1.1.2
echo "version="
version=
```

So I am not able to store version string in the variable and use it later,
I am not sure what am I doing wrong?

Any suggestion/pointer ?

After reading answer from "Didier Trosset" I changed my makefile as follows,

```
filepath        :=      $(PWD)
versionfile     :=      $(filepath)/verfile
myversion       :=      ""

all:

ifeq ($(wildcard $(versionfile)),)
all:
        echo "File not present"
else
all: myversion = $(shell cat $(versionfile))
endif
all:
        echo "myversion = $(myversion)"
```

and below is output for the

```
echo "myversion = v1.1.2"
myversion = v1.1.2
```

Answer (score 14):

You have two problems. First to have bash (and not make) expand the variable you need to use `$$version` (or `$${version}`). By this Make first translates `$$` into just `$` and then bash will see `$version` (or `${version}`).
Secondly each line in the rule will be executed as a separate command, so in order to let them interact via environmental variables you have to put them into a common subshell, enclosing with paranthesis.

```
filepath        :=      $(PWD)
versionfile     :=      $(filepath)/verfile

all:
    cat $(versionfile)
    (version=$(shell cat $(versionfile)); echo "version=$$version")
```

Comment: No need for the parens - each command in make is invoked in a shell anyway

Answer (score 7):

I usually prefer to have this version string in a `make` variable.

Therefore, I'd rather use the following that keeps variables into variables, and rules/target/commands in rules/target/commands.

```
filepath        :=      $(PWD)
versionfile     :=      $(filepath)/verfile
version         :=      $(shell cat $(versionfile))

info:
        echo "version=$(version)"
```

Note that here, `version` is a real make variable. (As opposed to a bash variable existing only in a lingle rule line of the target.)

---

If you need some commands to create the `versionfile` then it'd be better to create this file on its own target

```
filepath        :=      $(PWD)
versionfile     :=      $(filepath)/verfile

all: versionfile
        echo "version=$(version)"

all: version = $(shell cat $(versionfile))

versionfile:
        # Create your version file here
```

Note that you cannot use the `:=` anymore for the target variable: it would read the file at Makefile reading instead of when used, i.e. after `versionfile` target has been created.

Comment: But the problem is, I can use that version file only after running other commands as part of target ? can we set Makefile variable in the target `info` in your Makefile?

Comment: @AnkurTank Yes, this is possible. It's named target variables in GNU make. If you want to go this way, I'd suggest to create a target `versionfile`, with your actual building target depending on it, as in the answer edit.

Comment: @"Didier Trosset" Thank you for help, I have updated my aswer in question. Let me know ifyou see any improvment in that. Basic steps required were, 1. Check if version file present, 2. extract & store that version from the file. 3. Write & use version varible later.